# Remove Leading and Trailing Spaces from Rich Text Box using C# code

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, richhtmlfield, regex

I am using a MultiLine Rich Text box in my custom list, now I want to remove leading and trailing spaces in the MultiLine Rich text box's input.

I have written an List item event receiver with string.Trim() function and its not working on Rich Text box.

In the code, when I placed a debugger, I am getting the following values from the multiline text box. Below code is just an example, I may also apply Bold, color, etc to my text, accordingly the HTML code may vary.

```
"<html><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;sample&nbsp; Text&nbsp;&nbsp; </div></html>"
```

Now how to remove the leading and trailing spaces from MultiLine Rich text box.??

Thanks in advace. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably first decode the string from html, then trim it and then reencode it to html, like this:

```
var aString = yourTextBoxText;

aString= SPEncode.HtmlDecode(aString);
```

Since the texbox will always render `<html><div>` before the content

you can not use .Trim(), instead use:

```
aString = aString.Replace("<html> <div>", "");
aString = aString.Replace("</div> </html>", "");
```

and then

```
aString = aString.Trim();
```

and re add your html tags:

```
aString = "<html> <div>" + aString + "</div> </html>"
```

and encode:

```
aString = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(aString);
```

Quite extensive, would be great if there where som easier way!

Comment: Hi @Robert Lindgren, thanks for your reply. After HtmlDecode, I'm getting the following in the aString. <html> <div> Sample Test </div> </html>. I want to remove spaces before "Sample" and after "Test". Thanks in advace.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Hi @Robert Lindgren, thanks for your code and reply. As my List field is Rich Text box, I will be able to edit my text like applying color, bolding it, etc.. Now I applied Bold, color and underline to my text in the RichTextbox field and I got the below values after Htmlencodein the code. <html>
  <div>
<div><strong><em><font color="#99cc00"><u>        fds   </u>       </font></em></strong></div></div>
</html>.. I need a generalized code to remove spaces.

Comment: Well then it starts to get really hard for you, and you will probably need multiple trimming and replacing statements.

Comment: Like recursively calling .Replace("> ", ">") until you have no mor ocurrencies of a ">" followed by a blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
 string trimtext = Regex.Replace(text, @"s+", " ").Trim();
```

I hope it help.